# Why do i get error in unit testing jasmin/karma

Tags: npm, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

When I execute in command line `npm install karma-jasmine –save-dev` I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install karma-jasmine -save-dev
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Program Files\nodejs\-save-dev
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "karma-jasmine" "-save-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\-save-dev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\-save-dev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "karma-jasmine" "-save-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log.571fc1cbfa90babe4129ee8c4f66
eda5
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log.571fc1cbfa90b
abe4129ee8c4f66eda5'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log.571fc1cbf
a90babe4129ee8c4f66eda5']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm-debug.log.571fc1cbfa90babe4129e
e8c4f66eda5' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

"Program Files" is a special folder which requires admin access hence the eperm error.

If you need to install karma-jasmine globally use `npm install -g karma-jasmine`

If you need to install karma-jasmine locally for your project, use a different folder for the root of your project and use `npm install karma-jasmine`

see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders for more info.